# Why is this SKEmitterNode not showing up how it's supposed to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

```
    self._player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test.png"];
    __player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);

    SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
    trail.targetNode = self;
    trail.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(__player.frame), CGRectGetMidY(__player.frame));
    [__player addChild:trail];

    [self addChild:__player];
```

Above is the code I have for an SKEmitterNode to appear underneath an image I have, and follow the actions of the image as it is a child of the image. What happens is both the image and the SKEmitterNode show up, but in different locations. The player node shows up in the centre of the screen (as it should), and then the emitter node shows up at the top right hand corner of the screen, but still follows the course of the touches. So basically, they move the same, but have different locations. I don't understand why as the trail.position has a cgpoint make of the center of the player.

Any reasons why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was taking out the following line:

```
trail.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(__player.frame), CGRectGetMidY(__player.frame));
```

incase anyone has a similar problem.